# How to use controller variables along with ng-click to toggle class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-class

**http://plnkr.co/edit/nEfBE33AJen3mz9YvjeC?p=preview**

I have a list of tag buttons, by default after all the items are loaded, I set the first 3 items to have the `selected` class.

Now I also need tags to gain or lose the `selected` class on `ng-click`.

How would you combine the code in the markup or controller?

```
.controller('PageCtrl',
    ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

    var vs = $scope;
    vs.message = "1st, 2nd and 3rd item should be selected by default:";

    // Gives the 1st 3 items the selected class
    vs.toggleTags = { item: [0, 1, 2] };

    // the ng-click to individually toggle the selected class:
    vs.selectTag = function(term) {
        alert(term +' in tag #'+ vs.toggleTags.item);
    };

    vs.tags = [
      {name: 'aaa'},
      {name: 'bbb'},
      {name: 'ccc'},
      {name: 'ddd'},
      {name: 'eee'},
      {name: 'fff'},
      {name: 'ggg'}
    ];

}]);
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(k, m) in tags"
        ng-class="{'selected':toggleTags.item.indexOf(k) > -1}"
        ng-click="toggleTags.item = $index; selectTag(m.name)">
        <div class="tag">{{m.name}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically I'd like to combine something like: `{'selected' : toggle.state}` into the `ng-class` line. Right now my code deselects everything.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u dont want to change data you get from server - you can create selection model  separately:

```
<li ng-repeat="(k, m) in tags"
          ng-class="{'selected':selectedModel[$index]}"
          ng-click="selectedModel[$index] = !selectedModel[$index]">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QpoAs9XFknKug8mpNkkO?p=preview

Ofc, better to use ids not indexes, if u have any.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm liking this, I don't have to modify the JSON data and it's very clean, waiting to see what @yotamN is working on still...

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/bqXi4GHxJjbD03ilJ4Me?p=preview

New plnkr (for toggling):
http://plnkr.co/edit/bqXi4GHxJjbD03ilJ4Me?p=preview

You can do something like this. Using an extra variable inside your `tags`

```
vs.tags = [
  {name: 'aaa', active: true},
  {name: 'bbb', active: true},
  {name: 'ccc', active: true},
  {name: 'ddd', active: false},
  {name: 'eee', active: false},
  {name: 'fff', active: false},
  {name: 'ggg', active: false}
];
```

Comment: Thanks, 1 problem though and I should have mentioned this, my real data is actually coming in as JSON from an API call, and I can't change the objects. 2nd, your code does add the `selected` class on click, but it doesn't toggle.

Comment: you can make it toggle. and also you can add the `active` field once you get the data. this is most simple answer. 
might need to rethink if you do not want to add the fields.

Comment: Does the selected tags come from the API too? if so you can create a small script when you read the JSON that would add an active property to the tags object and set the actives tags to `true`.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the toggling, but to answer your question no the selected tags do not come from the API, I set that in the controller. It's just the first 3 items, but the code I have allows any tag to be pre-selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by updaing your controller function as :

```
 vs.selectTag = function(term,k) {
  if(vs.toggleTags.item.indexOf(k) == -1){
    vs.toggleTags.item.push(k)
  }
  else {
    vs.toggleTags.item.splice(vs.toggleTags.item.indexOf(k),1);
  }
    alert(term +' in tag #'+ vs.toggleTags.item);
};
```

And update html to:

```
<li ng-repeat="(k, m) in tags"
    ng-class="{'selected':toggleTags.item.indexOf(k) > -1}"
    ng-click="selectTag(m.name,k)">
    <div class="tag">{{m.name}}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too  :) +1 so many great answers for this question, going with @Petr's answer, but I like that yours takes advantage of the controller function as more logic can be included now!

Answer (score 0):

Every button have an object so instead of using another array to check if the button is checked you can add it to the existing object (`m` object in you code).

That way you can do `{'selected': m.state}` which is pretty clean.

As maddog showed, you just need to add the active property to the tags object and check there if it's selected and not in a different array, there is no reason for this (at least not one you have shown us).

Comment: Yes, but how would you combine that with this: `{'selected':toggleTags.item.indexOf(k) > -1}`

Comment: All this code does is check if the tag is selected and if it does the element get `selected` class so you can use it in the ng-class instead, I will edit and add example.